# Editing WordPress plugins (want to insert a code in anthor php file)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, include, required

I Want to use php file to insert
A code in a specific line
In anthor php file

Is that possible??

Because i want to edit plugin function and i didn't want it to change when plugin update

Comment: _"Is that possible??"_ - if it is a well-written plugin, then it should be using WP's hook/filter mechanism, to give people a chance to intercept the functionality and change behavior, from the outside. If it doesn't, then there is no general way to achieve this; whether it would be possible at all without directly modifying plugin files, would depend on the specifics.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit plugin files & change your aspect need. It will be better if you can extend the plugin by Class. Otherwise, you can change your style which is an easy method for you. After editing the plugin, you need to stop the plugin update. Simply prevent plugin updates by changing the plugin version in the plugin file, You set the plugin version upper which does not come. Example: 100

For a Better understanding, I attached a screenshot. https://prnt.sc/RutcGxXiCTpz